# fullpage.js, how to add stackable elements without scrollBar: true

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I have a bit of a problem and not sure how to address it. I really love how [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) works and functions! I'm hoping there is a solution to my problem using this great plugin, if not, any alternative suggestions are welcomed.

Basically, my problem is that it's possible for each slide to have overflowing content, hence I've enabled the `scrollOverflow: true` option to allowing scrolling in these sections.

My problem is, I want one of the sections to have three blocks of text that stack as you scroll, using something like this [jQuery vertical stack](https://github.com/matb33/jquery-vertical-stack) (demo [here](http://matb33.github.io/jquery-vertical-stack/)).

Now, I'm not sure how to do this without enabling `scrollBar: true`, which I don't want, as then I have two competing scroll bars (the default browser scroll bar, and the slimscroll scroll bar). I'm hoping there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured this out. If someone knows of a more elegant solution, I'm open to suggestions.

What I have, is on the homepage, there are three lines of text. I needed the first one to be displayed by default, and the other two lines to "slide" in as the user scrolled. Once all three lines were visible, the scrolling effect for pagePiling then returns to normal.

So first, I disabled pagePiling scrolling all together like so `$.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(false);`

Then used the `afterRender` call to use use my own scroll-jacking

```
afterRender: function(){
    //play the video BG for slide one
    $('video').get(0).play();   
    //disable scroll by default
    $.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(false);
    $.fn.pagepiling.setKeyboardScrolling(false);

    /****************************************
    * Disable scrolling until all text piled
    ****************************************/

    // Called when scrolling up/down
    var delayScrollEvent = debounce(function(event){
        var delta = 0;
        if (!event) event = window.event;
        if (event.wheelDelta) {
            delta = event.wheelDelta/120; 
            if (window.opera) delta = -delta;
        } else if (event.detail) {
            delta = -event.detail/3;
        }
        if (delta)
            handleScrollEvent(delta);
    }, 250, true);

    // Called when swiping/panning up/left/right
    var delaySwipeEvent = debounce(function(){
        wordStackCount++;
        // Scroll up statements
        if(wordStackCount == 1){
            $('#text1').animate({paddingTop: "0%"},800);
        }
        // Last statement, re-enable page scrolling
        if(wordStackCount > 1){
            $('#text2').animate({paddingTop: "0%"},600);
            $.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(true);
        }
    }, 80, true);

    // Debounce; credit David Walsh
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        if (wordStackCount > 3)
            return;
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };

    // Handle scrolling
    function handleScrollEvent(delta) {
        // Scrolling down
        if (delta < 0){
            // Increment count
            wordStackCount++;
            // Scroll up statements
            if(wordStackCount == 1){
                $('#text1').animate({paddingTop: "0%"},800);
            }
            // Last statement, re-enable page scrolling
            if(wordStackCount > 1){
                $('#text2').animate({paddingTop: "0%"},600);
                $.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling(true);
            }
        }
        // Else, scrolling up, ignore
    }

    // Action on mousewheel scroll
    // For FireFox
    if (window.addEventListener){
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', delayScrollEvent, false);
    }
    // For all other browsers
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = delayScrollEvent;

    // Swipe/pan event for touch devices; using Hammer.js
    mc.on("swipeup swipeleft swiperight panup panleft panright", delaySwipeEvent);

    /****************************************
    * End text pile scrolling stuff
    ****************************************/
}
```